# If statement using Numpy.Where and Pandas.Shift in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, if-statement, lambda

I have a DataFrame similar to below. I am trying to calculate a rolling count of how many times it switches from False to True.

```
Time   True/False
 1         0
 2         1
 3         1
 4         0
 5         0
 6         0
 7         1
 8         1
 9         0
 10        1
 11        0
```

The code below is what I have come up with using ```numpy.where, but I am not getting the results I want.

```
Test['RollingCount'] = np.where(Test['True/False'] == 0, Test['RollingCount'].shift(1),
                       np.where((Test['True/False'] == 1) & (Test['True/False'].shift(1) == 1), Test['RollingCount'].shift(1),
                       np.where((Test['True/False'] == 1) & (Test['True/False'].shift(1) == 0), (Test['RollingCount'].shift(1) + 1),
                       np.where(Test['True/False'] == 1, 1, 0))))
```

Below is the output I am trying to accomplish. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is there a better way to approach this?

```
Time   True/False   RollingCount
 1         0              0
 2         1              1
 3         1              1
 4         0              1
 5         0              1
 6         0              1
 7         1              2
 8         1              2
 9         0              2
 10        1              3
 11        0              3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df['RollingCount'] = df['True/False'].diff(-1).eq(1).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     2
8     2
9     3
10    3
Name: True/False, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

In numpy, you can do this with `diff` and `cumsum`:

```
d = np.concatenate(([0], np.diff(tf)))
result = np.cumsum(d[d > 0])
```